# Can't use chef-zero with vagrant files

Tags: chef, vagrant, chef-zero

I have a Vagrant (1.7.2) set up with 2 vms. I want to use chef (latest version now 12?) to provision them. I am trying to get one to be a nagios server and the other to be a machine monitored with nagios.

When using the [built in chef-zero vagrant provisioner](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_zero.html), each node can be configured fine. But the [community nagios cookbook](https://github.com/tas50/nagios) searches for nodes to monitor. Since each vagrant vm gets a fresh, local chef-zero, it doesn't know about the other hosts and so it isn't a real test of "chef-powered nagios".

This blog post ([Multi-node topologies using Vagrant and chef-zero](https://christinemdraper.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/multi-node-topologies-using-vagrant-and-chef-zero/)) seems to cover what I want to do, and advises that I run a chef-zero server on my local machine, and set that as the `chef_server_url` in teh Vagrantfile.

However when I do that, I get an error from the chef_client provisioner:

```
==> nagiosserver: [2015-01-23T15:59:09+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.0.3 ***
==> nagiosserver: [2015-01-23T15:59:09+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 6916
==> nagiosserver: [2015-01-23T15:59:12+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[rorytestvm1]"] from CLI options
==> nagiosserver: [2015-01-23T15:59:12+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found : Object not found: http://192.168.33.1:8889/roles/rorytestvm1
```

What's the solution?

*(There is a [vagrant chef-zero plugin](https://github.com/andrewgross/vagrant-chef-zero), but it hasn't been updated in ~8 months and [I, like others, experience bugs](https://github.com/andrewgross/vagrant-chef-zero/issues/61))*

Comment: Removed the devops tag.  It's essentially a meta tag, and given the way the community feels about devops, it probably isn't a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this. The problem was that I was starting `chef-zero` and leaving it there. I wasn't uploading any cookbooks/nodes/etc to it with `knife`. It was an empty server. I thought that chef-zero would use the nodes/cookbooks/etc in the current directory, but that is not the case.

I made a new `knife.rb` file, which had localhost as the server URL and did a `knife upload . -c /path/to/new/knife.rb` and it worked fine.